# Spring Boot : @Autowired remember and save the same object also for the next request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing a spring boot application , below one API for example :

```
@Autowired
GetUserIdByUserNameBase getUserIdByUserNameBase;

@PostMapping(value = "/UserName")
    public GetUserIdByUserNameOutput getUserIdByUserName(@RequestBody String userName) {
        GetUserIdByUserNameInput GetUserIdByUserNameInput = new GetUserIdByUserNameInput(userName);
    getUserIdByUserNameBase.setGetUserIdByUserNameInput(GetUserIdByUserNameInput);
    MsgStatus msgStatus = getUserIdByUserNameBase.execute();
    if (msgStatus == MsgStatus.ERROR_MSG) {
        LOG.error("UserRestController,getUserIdByUserName : Internal System Error");
    }
    return getUserIdByUserNameBase.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput();
}
```

My issue appear in the second/next request with the same API ( for example the above one )
"GetUserIdByUserNameBase" still remember all the saved data from the 
first hit!.

```
public class GetUserIdByUserNameBase extends ServiceBase {

    private final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(GetUserIdByUserNameBase.class);
    private GetUserIdByUserNameInput getUserIdByUserNameInput;
    private GetUserIdByUserNameOutput getUserIdByUserNameOutput;
    private ResultStatus resultStatus;
    private String userName;
    private TBUSER_INFO userInfo;
```

Here in my case, "getUserIdByUserNameOutput" still saving the previous 
data from the first hit of API until I override the content or mark it as 
empty.

1 . GetUserIdByUserNameBase.setGetUserIdByUserNameOutput(new GetUserIdByUserNameOutput );

or

2. GetUserIdByUserNameBase.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput().setX(Null);

but here I create one problem, Since I created a new instance of "GetUserIdByUserNameOutput" for every new API request and is not efficient and heavy for the system...

If I summarise what i want really to know , how I can tell @Autowired 
to bounce/rest the object on every new request of the API and not use or override what it remember from the first request.?

Here My full code :

```
package com.usermanagementms.ims.servicesfacade.userservices;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.usermanagementms.ims.enums.MsgStatus;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.repositories.userdao.TBUserInfoDao;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.tables.user.TBUSER_INFO;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.types.commontypes.ResultStatus;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.types.getuseridbyusername.GetUserIdByUserNameInput;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.types.getuseridbyusername.GetUserIdByUserNameOutput;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.utils.ErrorMsg;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.utils.ErrorsController;
import com.usermanagementms.ims.utils.Utils;

@Service
public class GetUserIdByUserNameBase extends ServiceBase {

    private final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(GetUserIdByUserNameBase.class);
    private GetUserIdByUserNameInput getUserIdByUserNameInput;
    private GetUserIdByUserNameOutput getUserIdByUserNameOutput;
    private ResultStatus resultStatus;
    private String userName;
        private TBUSER_INFO userInfo;

        @Autowired
        private TBUserInfoDao TBUserInfoDao;

        @Autowired
        private ErrorsController errorsController;

        @Transactional
        public TBUSER_INFO getUserIdByUserName(String username) {

            TBUSER_INFO userInfo;
            try {
                userInfo = TBUserInfoDao.findIdByUserName(username);
                if (userInfo == null) {
                    LOG.warn("UserService,getUserIdByUserName : userInfo is empty");
                    return null;
                }
                return userInfo;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("UserService,getUserIdByUserName : error in retrieving user from DB { " + e.getMessage() + "}");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public MsgStatus inputMapping() {
            MsgStatus msgStatus = MsgStatus.SUCCESS_MSG;
            this.setGetUserIdByUserNameOutput(new GetUserIdByUserNameOutput());
            if (getResultStatus() == null) {
                this.setResultStatus(new ResultStatus());
            }
            msgStatus = super.inputMapping();
            if (msgStatus == MsgStatus.ERROR_MSG || this.getUserIdByUserNameInput == null) {
                LOG.error("GetUserIdByUserNameBase,inpuMapping() : Internal System Error");
                this.getErrorsController().fillResultStatus(ErrorMsg.SYSTEM_ERROR, this.resultStatus);
                this.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput().setResultStatus(resultStatus);
                return MsgStatus.ERROR_MSG;
            }
            this.setUserName(getUserIdByUserNameInput.getUserNameX1());
            return MsgStatus.SUCCESS_MSG;
        }

        @Override
        public MsgStatus validate() {
            if (Utils.isNullorEmpty(userName)) {
                LOG.error("GetUserIdByUserNameBase,validate() : userName is null or empty");
                this.getErrorsController().fillResultStatus(ErrorMsg.REQUEST_BODY_EMPTY, this.resultStatus);
                this.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput().setResultStatus(resultStatus);
                return MsgStatus.ERROR_MSG;
            }
            return MsgStatus.SUCCESS_MSG;
        }

        @Override
        public MsgStatus executeImpl() {
            MsgStatus msgStatus = MsgStatus.SUCCESS_MSG;
            TBUSER_INFO userInfo = getUserIdByUserName(userName);
            this.setUserInfo(userInfo);
            if (userInfo == null) {
                msgStatus = this.getErrorsController().fillResultStatus(ErrorMsg.USER_NOT_FOUND, resultStatus);
                if (msgStatus == MsgStatus.ERROR_MSG) {
                    this.getErrorsController().fillResultStatus(ErrorMsg.SYSTEM_ERROR, resultStatus);
                    this.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput().setResultStatus(resultStatus);
                    LOG.error("GetUserIdByUserNameBase,executeImpl() : Internal System Error");
                    return MsgStatus.ERROR_MSG;
                }
                this.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput().setResultStatus(resultStatus);
                return MsgStatus.ERROR_MSG;
            }
            this.getErrorsController().fillResultStatus(ErrorMsg.OK, resultStatus);
            this.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput().setResultStatus(resultStatus);
            return MsgStatus.SUCCESS_MSG;
        }

        @Override
        public MsgStatus outputMapping() {
            this.getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput().setUserId(this.getUserInfo().getUid());
            return MsgStatus.SUCCESS_MSG;
        }

        public GetUserIdByUserNameInput getGetUserIdByUserNameInput() {
            return getUserIdByUserNameInput;
        }

        public void setGetUserIdByUserNameInput(GetUserIdByUserNameInput getUserIdByUserNameInput) {
            this.getUserIdByUserNameInput = getUserIdByUserNameInput;
        }

        public GetUserIdByUserNameOutput getGetUserIdByUserNameOutput() {
            return getUserIdByUserNameOutput;
        }

        public void setGetUserIdByUserNameOutput(GetUserIdByUserNameOutput getUserIdByUserNameOutput) {
            this.getUserIdByUserNameOutput = getUserIdByUserNameOutput;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public ErrorsController getErrorsController() {
            return errorsController;
        }

        public void setErrorsController(ErrorsController errorsController) {
            this.errorsController = errorsController;
        }

        public ResultStatus getResultStatus() {
            return resultStatus;
        }

        public void setResultStatus(ResultStatus resultStatus) {
            this.resultStatus = resultStatus;
        }

        public TBUSER_INFO getUserInfo() {
            return userInfo;
        }

        public void setUserInfo(TBUSER_INFO userInfo) {
            this.userInfo = userInfo;
        }
    }

public class GetUserIdByUserNameOutput {

    private Long UserId;
    private ResultStatus resultStatus;

    public GetUserIdByUserNameOutput() {

    }

    public GetUserIdByUserNameOutput(Long userId, ResultStatus resultStatus) {
        super();
        UserId = userId;
        this.resultStatus = resultStatus;
    }

    public GetUserIdByUserNameOutput(ResultStatus resultStatus) {
        this.resultStatus = resultStatus;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public ResultStatus getResultStatus() {
        return resultStatus;
    }

    public void setResultStatus(ResultStatus resultStatus) {
        this.resultStatus = resultStatus;
    }
}
```

If you look on this method :

```
public MsgStatus inputMapping() {
            MsgStatus msgStatus = MsgStatus.SUCCESS_MSG;
            this.setGetUserIdByUserNameOutput(new GetUserIdByUserNameOutput());
```

I start to create "new GetUserIdByUserNameOutput()" all the time with every request for the same API!! , and I guess is not efficient and heavy for the system for creating a lot of instance of GetUserIdByUserNameOutput after some times ...

Comment: had been deleted

Comment: Can you share the code to the methods in your GetUserIdByUserNameBase class?

Comment: Please find the edited post :)

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". There are several ways of how to keep data across requests if you _really_ need to, like application caches, in-memory-stores, ORM cache etc. Don't try it in a bean that is meant to be stateless like Spring Service Beans.

Comment: You really need to review some concepts of Spring Boot and Java. You could easily reduce your code by 80-90%. For example, getUserIdByUserName(String username) could contain just a single line of code. Moreoever, there is no need to catch exceptions there as you don't go and handle them anyway, you just log them, which should be done by an ExceptionHandler. Furthermore, stick to Java coding conventions: don't start a class name with Get (or verbs) or use method names that doesn't describe what they exactly do, like inputMapping or validate.

Comment: HI Matt ,
I understand your point of view , 
Regartding the name concept I agree with you , but here in my case
is the API name not more ...
regarding the handle the exception , I really do it and handle the exception and back to the user with result status object regarding the error.
I didnt attche the whole code , Since you didnt get where I treat this exception.
regarding the  "ExceptionHandler" mechanism I really aware about this
but the issue with this mechanism that return the status error in the header for the user like "200" "201" "404" and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring beans, in the large majority of cases, should not have state. A bean is a single instance of a class that is re-used. Do not use setters!

Instead of doing this:

`getUserIdByUserNameBase.setGetUserIdByUserNameInput(GetUserIdByUserNameInput);`

You need to do the calculation in a single method, or perhaps instantiate a new object inside the bean and return the new object, e.g.

```
return getUserIdByUserNameBase.getGetUserIdByUserName(GetUserIdByUserNameInput);
```

or something like

```
return getUserIdByUserNameBase.buildUsernameThing(GetUserIdByUserNameInput).execute();
```

Comment: what about "GetUserIdByUserNameInput" ? its ok to create in every request
a new instance of "GetUserIdByUserNameInput" and start the execute()?

in my case if I still using the setters , can i do something like this ?
if ( getUserIdByUserNameBase.getGetUserIdByUserNameInput() != null ){
   getUserIdByUserNameBase.getGetUserIdByUserNameInput().setUserName(userName)
}

Comment: @PostMapping(value = "/UserName")
 public GetUserIdByUserNameOutput getUserIdByUserName(@RequestBody String userName) {
  if (getUserIdByUserNameBase.getGetUserIdByUserNameInput() != null) {
   getUserIdByUserNameBase.getGetUserIdByUserNameInput().setUserNameX1(userName);
  } else {
   GetUserIdByUserNameInput GetUserIdByUserNameInput = new GetUserIdByUserNameInput(userName);
   getUserIdByUserNameBase.setGetUserIdByUserNameInput(GetUserIdByUserNameInput);
  }

Comment: No, you shouldn't use setters at all like that in your Spring beans. Your Spring bean has state in that case. In other words, your Spring bean has fields that change each request when it should not. You're having issues with one client already. What happens if 10 clients hit that code at the same time? They'll all be getting the same username info. You should review Spring concepts before continuing. You need to pass in all the data the service class needs to do its work through a method call and do ALL the work inside the method. You should not be using mutable fields inside the bean.